# json_decode is not working on my variable but is on its content

Tags: php, json

I have the following piece of code:

```
$param = $params[0];
var_dump($param->getValue());
$test = json_decode($param->getValue());
var_dump($test);
```

my first var_dump returns the following:

```
string(133) ""[{\"lang_id\": \"1\", \"naam\": \"dsfsdfds\", \"mail\": \"dsfdsfs\"}, {\"lang_id\": \"1\", \"naam\": \"dfsd\", \"mail\": \"dfds\"}]""
```

the seconde one is returning the following:

```
string(107) "[{"lang_id": "1", "naam": "dsfsdfds", "mail": "dsfdsfs"}, {"lang_id": "1", "naam": "dfsd", "mail": "dfds"}]"
```

and the value is saved in my DB like this:

```
"[{\"lang_id\": \"1\", \"naam\": \"dsfsdfds\", \"mail\": \"dsfdsfs\"}, {\"lang_id\": \"1\", \"naam\": \"dfsd\", \"mail\": \"dfds\"}]"
```

Now my question is: Why is it returning a string after the json_decode?
I have absolutely no idea what i'm doing wrong and the strangest thing is that if i replace the variable with the actual value of that variable then the decode is correct:

```
$test = json_decode("[{\"lang_id\": \"1\", \"naam\": \"dsfsdfds\", \"mail\": \"dsfdsfs\"}, {\"lang_id\": \"1\", \"naam\": \"dfsd\", \"mail\": \"dfds\"}]");
```

returns

```
array(2) { 
    [0]=> object(stdClass)#3255 (3) { 
        ["lang_id"]=> string(1) "1" 
        ["naam"]=> string(8) "dsfsdfds" 
        ["mail"]=> string(7) "dsfdsfs" 
     } 
    [1]=> object(stdClass)#3256 (3) { 
        ["lang_id"]=> string(1) "1" 
        ["naam"]=> string(4) "dfsd" 
        ["mail"]=> string(4) "dfds" 
     } 
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because your string is json_encoded twice, so you need to decode it twice.

```
string(133) ""[{\"lang_id\": \"1\", \"naam\": \"dsfsdfds\", \"mail\": \"dsfdsfs\"}, {\"lang_id\": \"1\", \"naam\": \"dfsd\", \"mail\": \"dfds\"}]""
```

if you look in the string above you see that all he quotes are escaped and there is a double quote in the beginning and in the end. so this means if you json decode you get an string withouth the escaped quotes.

if you decode again the string will be decoded to an array.

```
json_decode('"[12,24,32]"'); //php string:  [12,24,32]
json_decode('[12,24,32]'); //php array(12, 24, 32);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your entire string is wrapped in quotes.

It is a JSON string, but it's a JSON string that contains just a single string variable.... that string variable itself contains a valid JSON string, but as far as the JSON decode is concerned, that fact is irrelevant; it only sees the JSON a being a single string variable.

You can prove this by doing a `json_decode()` on the decoded output: you should then get the array you're expected.

It looks as if your data has been double-encoded somehow. So although doing a second decode will give you the result you want, I'd suggest that rather than trying to fix the problem by double-decoding, you should try to find out where the double-encoding is happening and fix that.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

your sting is not a valid json (escape quotes).

```
$atring = '[{"lang_id": "1", "naam": "dsfsdfds", "mail": "dsfdsfs"}, {"lang_id": "1", "naam": "dfsd", "mail": "dfds"}]';
```

use the JSON Fromatter tool to check if you string is avalid json. http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/